# Error request for member 'nome' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

Opa, alguém consegue me ajudar? Não consigo ver onde estou errando, aparece esse erro que está no título na linha "printf("Nome do aluno: %s", aluno.nome);"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct notas_dos_alunos{
    char disc[20];
    float P1;
}notas;

typedef struct endereco_dos_alunos{
    char rua[50];
    int numero;
}endereco;

typedef struct cadastro_dos_alunos{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    endereco ender;
    notas nota;
}cadastro;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    cadastro aluno[15];
    
    printf("Nome do aluno: ");
    gets(aluno[0].nome);
    printf("Idade do aluno: ");
    scanf("%d", &aluno[0].idade);
    
    printf("Endereço do aluno: ");
    gets(&aluno[0].ender.rua);
    printf("Número de residência do aluno: ");
    gets(&aluno[0].ender.numero);
    
    printf("Digite a disciplina: ");
    scanf("%f", &aluno[0].nota.disc);
    printf("Digite a nota do aluno nessa disciplina: ");
    scanf("%f", &aluno[0].nota.P1);
    
    printf("Nome do aluno: %s", aluno.nome);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %d", aluno.idade);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %s", aluno.ender.rua);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %d", aluno.ender.numero);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %s", aluno.nota.disc);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %.2f", aluno.nota.P1);
    

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cadastro aluno[15];
```

`aluno` é cadastro[15], um vetor.

```
    typedef struct cadastro_dos_alunos{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    endereco ender;
    notas nota;
}cadastro;
```

`nome` é `char[50]` então pode ser uma string se tiver um 0 entre esses 50 `char`

Então

```
   printf("Nome do aluno: %s", aluno.nome);
```

não serve. Só pode usar `aluno[0].nome` a `aluno[14].nome`

Há outros erros em seu programa.

Apenas para você poder compilar e comparar assim estaria ok:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct notas_dos_alunos
{
    char  disc[20];
    float P1;
} notas;

typedef struct endereco_dos_alunos
{
    char rua[50];
    int  numero;
} endereco;

typedef struct cadastro_dos_alunos
{
    char     nome[50];
    int      idade;
    endereco ender;
    notas    nota;
} cadastro;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    cadastro aluno[15];

    printf("Nome do aluno: ");
    gets(aluno[0].nome);
    printf("Idade do aluno: ");
    scanf("%d", &aluno[0].idade);

    printf("Endereço do aluno: ");
    gets(&aluno[0].ender.rua);
    printf("Número de residência do aluno: ");
    gets(&aluno[0].ender.numero);

    printf("Digite a disciplina: ");
    scanf("%s", &aluno[0].nota.disc);
    printf("Digite a nota do aluno nessa disciplina: ");
    scanf("%f", &aluno[0].nota.P1);

    printf("Nome do aluno: %s", aluno[0].nome);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %d", aluno[0].idade);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %s", aluno[0].ender.rua);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %d", aluno[0].ender.numero);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %s", aluno[0].nota.disc);
    printf("Nota do aluno: %.2f", aluno[0].nota.P1);

    return 0;
}
```